# Need an async function, running inside another function, to return a boolean instead of a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, dataframe

I am trying to use the `chain` function from `dataframe-js` module, https://gmousse.gitbooks.io/dataframe-js/content/doc/api/dataframe.html#chain, and using NodeJS.

The documentation states `If a function returns boolean, it's a filter.` which is what I want. I need one of my filter lines to run async because part of the logic requires an API call for data that it will try to match against.

I intended my chain to look something like this:

```
let filteredDf = df.chain(
    row => ![null, '<SLID>'].includes(row.get('SERVICE_ACCT_NBR')), // this works fine
    async row => {
        const account = row.get('ACCOUNT')
        const manager_chain = await getManagersChain(account) // API call, returns an array of managerIds 
        returns (['6G0001', '330002'].some(managerId => manager_chain.includes(managerId)))
    }
)
```

Need to keep accounts that contain at least one of these two managerIds

What ends up happening is that the async function gives a Promise which is seen as `true` regardless of the actual value.

I started a blank test file to try and figure out how to return a bool, but I can't find a solution:

```
const DataFrame = require('dataframe-js').DataFrame;
let df2 = new DataFrame([
        {col1: '1', col2: '1a'},
        {col1: '2', col2: '2a'},
        {col1: '3', col2: '3a'}
    ], ['col1', 'col2'])

// non-async get [3,2]
console.log(df2.chain(
    row => true
).dim())
// non-async get [0,2]
console.log(df2.chain(
    row => false
).dim())

// expected [0,2] for both but got [3,2]
console.log(df2.chain(
    async row => false
).dim())
console.log(df2.chain(
    row => (async () => false)()
).dim())
```

How can I get the async function to return a bool so I can run that await inside of it?

Comment: `async` functions **ONLY** return promises. You cannot return an async value within a non-async function without using async (or a promise).

Comment: You will either need a filter interface designed for asynchronous operations or you will need to somehow prefilter or prefetch data before filtering so you can consult the data synchronously to operate the filter.